# How to load multiple packages using a package

Tags: r, r-package

I'm creating an internal package, and one of the functions I want is to load all the packages we use commonly.  If I include them in depends, the functions are available to my packages functions, but what I want it for them to be in the search path.

Basically I want to do what the tidyverse package does (loading all the core tidyverse packages for use in the global env).  I've looked through the tidyverse code, and I cannot find the line that does the actual loading - all the functions appear to be either cosmetic (the awesome, colorful startup messages) or utilties.  The `.onAttach` seems like where it would be, but nothing there appears to actually attach the other packages.

If there is a simpler way than how tidyverse does it, that's great, but I'm also curious about that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.onAttach` calls `tidyverse_attach()` (https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/blob/master/R/zzz.R#L7), which loads packages using `library` (https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/blob/master/R/attach.R#L37-L39).

Comment: Goddamnit the apply family always gets me.  Thank you.